# Manipulate Select options with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

lets admit we have two selects

```html
<select id=first>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select id=second>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

I want that the second select should not offer values that are bigger then the selected value in the first select, so if for example in the first select I selected `3` then the second select should offer

```html
<select id=second>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

So I went like this :

```js
    $(#first).on('change', function() {
        var min = $(#first).val();
        for (let i = 1; i <= min; i++) {
           $(#second).append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>'); 
        } 
    });
```

But this appends options. I want to replace the options.

Comment: Is there a reason you are declaring a min variable twice in your 'change' function?

Comment: @GenericUser no, that's not necessary, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all `<option>` tags first by using `.empty()` and then append new `<option>` tags by loop:

```js
    $('#first').on('change', function() {
        $('#second').empty();
        var min = $('#first').val();
        for (let i = 1; i <= min; i++) {
            $('#second').append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Different approach where you store a set of the options and filter the set to replace existing with

```js
const $storedOpts = $('#second option').clone()

$('#first').change(function(){
    const $opts = $storedOpts .clone().filter((i,el) => el.value <= this.value)
    $('#second').html($opts);      
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id=first>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select id=second>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: nice, very nice :) but would you please explain the function inside of filer?

Comment: Explain what part? filter() expects a boolean returned and I am checking the current option instance value to the `select` value. See [filter() docs](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)